# Using Drupal services module, Global $user->uid returns for non admin users only

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

The title pretty much says it all.  I have a custom service and it works great for everyone but the admins, but with admins it is not retrieving the UID.

What's also odd is that  **user_access('administer')**   returns true if the user is indeed an admin.

Does anyone have any idea why this could be/how to fix it so my poor admin can use the service the same as everyone else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you do this? (as you didn't show any code)

```
    global $user;
    echo $user->uid;
// or do whatever
```